# Joining table in ArcGIS Desktop but join field is greyed out?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, csv, attribute-joins

I'm trying to join a shapefile with an Excel file I converted into a CSV. I had done this before with the same shapefile but with a different CSV but this time when I try to select the column it's removed from the join list. I have tried exporting the CSV as DBF then turning it back into a CSV as well which did not work. I have included two screenshots below. I want to use the column PCODE3 because it shares the same data as MUN_P_6. Screenshots:

Full list of fields:

[image]

Limited list of fields:

[image]

Comment: Open the excel table with the Add data button (select the relevant sheet). Use [Table to table conversion](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000027000000) to give it OID's (or [Excel to table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000055000000) in 10.2). Use [Join Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000) to join it to an existing shapefile/feature class.

Answer (score 4):

Verify that the field type of PCODE3 is the same as the field type of MUN_P_. You can't join fields with different types.

Comment: How do I do that? I set it to text in excel but I didn't think CSVs kept any formatting data like that.

Comment: Look at the field properties of the csv in ArcGIS, you will see how ArcGIS reads it. It will be text anyway if there are alphanumeric values. If the field types are different, add a new field with the right format to your shapefile and copy the values from the join field (MUN_P_6) to it.